# append to each line in a file in ant

Tags: regex, ant

I'm trying to do some minor file manipulation in ant. I retrieve a list of tablespaces that I'd like to prepend with ALTER TABLESPACE  and append with NOT LOGGED like so:

```
    <loadfile property="zos.prepend.tablespaces" srcFile="${basedir}/zos-tablespaces-DIRTY.txt">
      <filterchain>
        <!-- Order here is important -->
        <prefixlines prefix="ALTER TABLESPACE "/>
        <suffixlines suffix=" NOT LOGGED"/>
        <trim/>
        <replaceregex pattern=".*NAME.*|.*-----.*|.*record.*select.*|^ALTER TABLESPACE$" replace=""/>
        <trim/>
        <ignoreblank/>
      </filterchain>
    </loadfile>

    <echo file="${basedir}/zos-tablespaces-PREPEND.txt">
        ${zos.prepend.tablespaces}
    </echo>
```

When I do this, I get the prepending ok, but the appending seems to append to the next line. Any ideas how to do the prefix and suffix?

Comment: Can you provide your example of file input and output? I think the problem is in your regexp.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just figured it out. I the suffixlines was adding after the CRLF at the end of each of the lines of my input, rather than just before. So I just had to clear the CRLF after suffixing. This is what eventually worked. now I just need to make it a little cleaner

```
<filterchain>

  <tabstospaces/>
  <prefixlines prefix="ALTER TABLESPACE "/>
  <trim/>
  <replaceregex pattern=".*NAME.*|.*record.*select.*|.*-----.*|^ALTER TABLESPACE$" replace=""/>
  <suffixlines suffix=" NOT LOGGED @"/>
  <striplinebreaks/>
  <tokenfilter>
  <replacestring from="LOGGED @" to="LOGGED @${line.separator}"/>
  </tokenfilter>
  <tabstospaces/>
  <trim/>
  <replaceregex pattern="^NOT LOGGED @$" replace=""/>
  <tabstospaces/>
  <trim/>       
  <ignoreblank/>
  <fixcrlf eol="crlf" eof="add"/>

</filterchain>
```